# WPF Datagrid Update

Tags: c#, wpf, file, datagrid, upload

Good day everyone.

I am quite new to wpf application and I created this file upload/download application using wpf.

Basically user will upload the file into the server and the database will record the file information and display it on a wpf data grid.

How the user upload is on the application, there is an upload button, which when clicked, will open a dialog for them to select a file to upload. After uploading, the dialog will close. However, the datagrid was not updated. It will only update whenever I restart the application.
I have try to use datagrid.item.refresh() but it won't work.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you add the item to the datagrid after the dialog closes?

Comment: Can't help without looking at the code.

Comment: Without looking at your code, I am assuming the UI is not updated due the database not binded properly with the controls of your WPF Application, in this case, the datagrid.

However, I cant say for sure without looking at your code.